# Where are the Dictionary.app dictionary files located in MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: terminal, finder, dictionary

Where in the filesystem are the dictionary files used in the native Mac Dictionary app located? In previous OSes, they were in Library/Dictionary. I don't see that directory in MacOS Big Sur.

More importantly, how could I effectively search for them? I tried searching my whole computer in the Finder for the keywords "dictionary" and "oxford english", and they didn't appear. Are the files hidden? Would there be a good terminal command to fuzzy keyword search all files including hidden ones? Or, would it be possible to see what files the Dictionary app uses by examining the app, somehow?

Answer (score 4):

The Finder (Spotlight) doesn't include system files in its results.

Dictionaries are now downloaded when selected, so they fall into the murky file path of:

```
/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX
```

inside various "AssetData" subfolders.

I recommend EasyFind as a good all-purpose real-time file searcher.
https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware